# Sharing Records

Tags: trigger, dml, apex-managed-sharing

I have an org that was recently updated to API 32, which broke some triggers that create Sharing Records.  This code worked previously to the update to API 32.

```
public void OnAfterObjectInsert(List<Object__c> insertRecords) {
  List<Object__Share> newShares = new List<Object__Share>();
  List<AccountShare> clientShares = [SELECT Id,AccountId,RowCause,UserOrGroupId FROM AccountShare WHERE AccountId = :insertRecords[0].Client__c];
  for (AccountShare cs : clientShares) {
    if(cs.UserOrGroupId != Userinfo.getUserId()) {
      Object__Share curShare    = new Object__Share();
      curShare.ParentId         = insertRecords[0].id;
      curShare.RowCause         = 'Test__c'; //or Schema.Object__Share.RowCause.Test__c;
      curShare.UserOrGroupId    = cs.UserOrGroupId;
      curShare.AccessLevel      = 'Edit';
      newShares.add(curShare);
    }
  }
  insert newShares;
}
```

This is returning a DML exception.  The reported error is "invalid row cause."  Using Manual as the RowCause works, and interestingly inserting a record with workbench.developerforce.com with Test__c as a RowCause works as well.  I've also set the api of the relevant class to 32, which had no effect.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Test__c a valid RowCause? They may have added some validation that you can only use a custom cause if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced and same issue today and my solution may work in this case.

What I did is, removed "with sharing" from class and worked fine. I think when we use with sharing, user doesn't have access to add the manual sharing.

Comment: Yes in general your classes that manipulate sharing should be run `without sharing` because most users don't have rights on them.