# DML Exception while inserting share records

Tags: apex, dmlexception

I am facing trouble while `inserting` 1 `share record`. When I am loggin to `Admin Profile`, it is working fine without any `DML exception`, but when I am login to `Sales profile`, then I am facing such exception.

I checked with `DescriveSObject` `isCreatable`() method, I can see that Sales profile has create access on `Package_Share__c` object.

**This is the list I am inserting:**

```
packageShareInsertList : (Package__Share:{UserOrGroupId=00540000000zHI5AAM, ParentId=a1I560000004iRIEAY, RowCause=PKG_Sales_Team__c, AccessLevel=Edit})
```

**This is th DML Exception I am facing:**

> 04:21:17.791 (3215279840)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AssertException:
>   Assertion Failed: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception
>   on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, invalid row
>   cause: []:

But `Row cause` has valid value that I am sure. If it was a wrong value, then other `profiles` would have thrown the same issue.

Please advise.

Comment: I guess its a custom apex sharing reason

Comment: Use RowCause = Schema.Package_Share__c.RowCause.PKG_Sales_Team__c, assuming the object name is Package_Share__c

Comment: @Stygon : yes, `RowCause=PKG_Sales_Team__c`. `PKG_Sales_Team__c` is the custom Apex sharing reason on `Package__c` custom object.

Comment: The way you are assigning rowcause in ur code is wrong, please do so as 
RowCause = Schema.Package__Share.RowCause.PKG_Sales_Team__c

Comment: For using custom rowcause, please see line 34 in the code snippet of this page - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic

Comment: @Stygon : I dont think so that is the reason. I have tested with your solution, same issue is happening.

`Schema.Package__Share.RowCause.PKG_Sales_Team__c` gives you string value and `RowCause` data type is string, so I think we can assign that way too.

If assigning value was wring, then how it i sworking for `Admin profile`.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for that then :)

Comment: @Stygon : Thanx for trying. much appriciate :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are having the issues because the user you are trying does not have "**Modify all data**" permission.

According to the documentation [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

> Apex managed sharing enables developers to pro-grammatically
>   manipulate sharing to support their application’s behavior through
>   Apex or the SOAP API. This type of sharing is similar to Force.com
>   managed sharing. **Only users with “Modify All Data” permission can add
>   or change Apex managed sharing on a record. Apex managed sharing is
>   maintained across record owner changes**.

I came across another answer where this was successfully achieved via changing class's sharing model as "**without sharing**". Please try doing that as well.

[Link to the Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53784/sharing-records)

---

**EDIT**

I believe you received error using with sharing because a user requires at-least read access to the record for which the share is to be created. [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

> If a trigger changes the owner of a record, the running user must
>   have read access to the new owner’s user record if the trigger is
>   started through the following:

Comment: With Sharing was the issue here. I have changed my class back to without sharing and it worked like charm. Thanx:)

Comment: I had the same issue with this. Normally, triggers operate in the "System Context",  so I don't see why this operation should generate an error for classes that are "with sharing".  However, I was able to get it to work by removing "with sharing" entirely - thus letting the class inherit the sharing mode from the calling trigger.